# Select Only Printed Out Cells

Tags: notebooks, cells, document-creation

Is there a way to select only printed out cells in *Mathematica*?

I'm using version 10.  I'm told this works in version 11 almost not sure though `SelectionMove[First@Cells[CellStyle -> "Output"], All, Cell]`.

I would like to copy all printed out cells to another notebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach which doesn't change the selection and should be more efficient when working with huge Notebooks:

```
CreateDocument@NotebookRead@Cells[CellStyle -> "Print"]
```

Comment: What version of M are you using?

Comment: @Liam *Mathematica* 11.0.0, checked with version 10.4.1 as well. This solution should work starting from version 9 where the function `Cells` was introduced.

Comment: `CreateDocument@NotebookRead@Cells[CellStyle -> "Output"]` works so maybe this is my fault and my question was worded poorly.

Comment: @Liam `CellStyle -> "Print"` is for cells created by the `Print` command, `CellStyle -> "Output"` is for usual output cells.

Comment: Is this the best way to select both `Join[Cells[CellStyle -> "Output"], Cells[CellStyle -> "Print"]]`.

Comment: @Liam No -- unless you don't mind losing the order of the cells. Best to do this: `CreateDocument@NotebookRead@Cells[CellStyle -> ("Print" | "Output")]`

Answer (score 11):

Here is a quick way of doing it:

```
NotebookFind[nb = EvaluationNotebook[], "Print", All, CellStyle];
CreateDocument[NotebookRead[nb]]
```

[image]